# tikz: plot 2 curves with "very close" y values

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots

With the following code:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
 \begin{axis}[black,
  ylabel=Density,xmin=-0.1,xmax=1.1]
  \addplot+[blue] table[col sep=comma] {RTC0_density.csv};
  \addlegendentry{Target $=0$}
  \addplot+[red] table[col sep=comma] {RTC1_density.csv};
  \addlegendentry{Target $=1$}
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
```

I plotted the figure:

[image]

How we can see, the curves are too close to each other and we cannot appreciate the differences. How could I go about "separating" the curves? By adding `ymode=log` I obtained too oscillating trends due to the abscissa value too close to 1. With `xmode=log` I obtained instead:

[image]

which I think is clearer than the previous one. Anyone have any other ideas?

Thank you!

Comment: Do you want to show that the curves has different y values between x=0.1 and x=1 ? Non of your examples show that. The way to show that and still show the high value near x=0.001 is to have a logarithmic y axis. We can not tell you how to plot your data, as you do not explain what they are. What do you mean by "too oscillating trends"?

Comment: Can you provide your data? Do you need the marks for each data point, or would a line withput them be better for visualisation?!